# locate `pre-commit` and not `pre-commit.sample`

Tags: terminal

I would like to find all files named `pre-commit`, the problem is that I also find `pre-commit.sample`.

`locate pre-commit`.

How can I find the files that don't have the `.sample` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locate` uses shell-style globbing so the options for the pattern are kind of limited.

The simple way probably is to just run

```
locate pre-commit | grep -v 'sample$'
```

Or you could make use of the special case documented in `man locate`

```
As a special case, a pattern containing no globbing characters (``foo'') is matched as
though it were ``*foo*''.
```

and use `locate 'pre?commit'` (quoting is required to prevent the shell from expanding the pattern) to prevent the automatic adding of the `*` wildcard.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it working. If I change`'sample$'` to. `'pre-commit$'` I still get all the files ending with `sample`.

Comment: @clankill3r Did you copy/paste the line from the answer? If not, either do so or add a comment with the command you are running.

Comment: It works, it was the first thing I did, but I guess the output from the previous attempts was still above it, making me think that it didn't work. Thx for the help.